# SQL injection prevention advice

Tags: sql, code-injection

Some script kiddie has been trying to SQL inject into my site. The logs shows he's been entering 'emails' and other form fields with info like "waitfor delay" something and other junk.

I use escape strings but just wanted to check this is safe, eg:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[email]);
$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='". $email. "'", $db); 
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result);
```

Comment: why don't you use sql parameters ?

Comment: Looks save for this query. But better update all your code to use mysqli_query, since mysql_real_escape_string not going to work on non-strings, i.e. integers, float etc

Comment: I'd recommend creating a stored procedure for what you want to do & pass in your parameters as safe-escaped parameters.

Comment: install a CAPTCHA on your form. "some script kiddie" is not sitting there trying emails manually...

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string works fine on non-strings as long as you remember putting them into quotes. (The code looks fine - the problem is probably caused by a script looking for weaknesses.)